# C# Regex local error "unrecognized escape sequence \\d." but works in production

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am facing an odd situation here where a regex works in production but doesn`t work locally.

In one part of the code, we need to create an HTML Label element for regex`s. So there is this method that receives a string as parameter (the regex) and does some treatments. One of the treatments is to Unescape the received parameter.

My trouble regex string is: `@"^ *P\.\d{3}"` expecting to get the pattern: P.###

The code using the regex is: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(regex);`

In Production it runs ok, but locally I am facing an exception with the message: `parsing " P\.\d{3}" - Unrecognized escape sequence \d.`

Locally, I have tried these two codes and both threw error:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(@"*P\.\d{3}");
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape("*P\\.\\d{3}");
```

How come production server can unescape this regex but not my local machine?

Comment: stupid question, the .net framework version is the same? also, you are sure the code is the same?

Comment: @BagusTesa the framework version is 4.6.1 on both scenarios.

Comment: thats weird, `@"^ *P\.\d{3}"` should mean the `\d` does not need to be escaped.. but, just to be sure, could you decompile the code on production using [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) or equivalent? i could not think of another scenario..

Comment: @BagusTesa I will try to decompile. About your other comment, do you mean the string value could be: @"^ *P.d{3}", without the slashes?

Comment: no, in Regex you had `\d` for denoting numbers. without the `@` you will need to use double slash (`\\d` instead)...

Comment: why does `@"^ *P\.\d{3}"` need to be `Unescape`d? That looks ready to go in either a Regex constructor, or `Regex.Match` / `Regex.Matches`. I'm confused.

Comment: @spender actually it is a method that receives an unknown regex as parameter, and treats it to be displayed as a HTML label as a text. So, one of the treatment is this line to Unescape.

Comment: Shown as a label where exactly?

Comment: Do not unescape the `@"^ *P\.\d{3}` as what it does is replaces literal backslash+char (2 char) sequences into string escape sequences consisting of the backslash and a char. That is, you may unescape `@"\n"` string because `\n` is a newline char inside a string literal. `\d` is not a valid string escape sequence, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think method Unescape() cannot pars `\d`

So ,you can use this:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(" *P\\.") + "\\d{3}";
```

Or

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(" *P\\.[0-9]{3}");
```

[More information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx)